# Why this question is deleted?

Tags: discussion

What are the reasons to delete this question: https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/923
Since, it is deleted and folks can not find that, I restate the title of the question for the purpose of the discussion.

> Why does Tor use three hops instead of Four? Or even better why Tor
>   does not use random number of hops greater than or equal to Four?

The question was marked as duplicate by a moderator, I was editing the question and intended to request to reopen the question at a proper time in future. But the action to delete that was surprising if not shocking!

Answer (score 2):

After a discussion in the moderator chat room, there was a cleanup of a few old questions that weren't likely to be reopened.

That particular question had a lot of small edits, but nothing that looked like it actually made the question unique (they were just bumping it back to the top of the list and not providing any real value; generally, small spelling or grammar edits are discouraged as they simply bump more current questions off the front page, preventing them from getting as many views / potentially answers).

If you have a way to change it to not be a duplicate, please ask a new question (don't just copy / paste from the old one, this will most likely get it closed again).

Thanks!